# Use ssh key from remote server to connect to git

Tags: linux, ssh, git

I have a laptop with its ssh key added to github. I can work with any of my repos from this laptop without any issues.

I also have a desktop computer but the ssh keys of this computer are **not added** to github.

I want to ssh into my laptop from the desktop computer and work from there, however, I cannot use git while doing ssh because it seems that even though I'm logged into my laptop git is using the ssh keys of my desktop computer.

What can I do to force git to use the SSH keys of the machine I am ssh'ing to ?

Edit: I am not connecting to git in a different terminal.

Here is an example. I connect to github (via ssh) to check which user is authenticated with my ssh keys.

All these command are run in the same terminal in my desktop PC:

```
(base) gonzalo@DESKTOP:~$ hostname
DESKTOP
(base) gonzalo@DESKTOP:~$ ssh git@github.com
Hi Gonzalo933! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
(base) gonzalo@DESKTOP:~$ ssh laptop
(base) gonzalo@laptop:~$ hostname
laptop
(base) gonzalo@laptop:~$ ssh git@github.com
Hi Gonzalo933! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

As you can see even though I'm logged via ssh to my laptop I still the github user "Gonzalo933"

Now these commands are run in my laptop physically

```
(base) gonzalo@laptop:~$ hostname
laptop
(base) gonzalo@laptop:~$ ssh git@github.com
Hi gonzalo*****! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

Now the user is different even though it's the same machine I connect via SSH earlier (I hid part of the name for privacy reasons)

Comment: ”it seems that even though I'm logged into my laptop git is using the ssh keys of my desktop computer”—very unlikely but your description is probably incorrect. Are you using Git in this SSH connection? // Opening a SSH connection does not allow you to impersonate the remote host. Only commands running on the remote host will use its configuration and identity.

Comment: @DanielB Yeah, I'm using Git via SSH. I'm not impersonating the remote host, I'm logged as my user which has ssh private keys in the `/home/laptop_user/.ssh` folder. Wouldn't that be enough to connect to git as the `laptopt_user` instead of `desktop_user` ?

Comment: No, only if you issue Git commands _inside_ the SSH session, so they run on the remote host. That’s why I am asking: Is this what you’re doing? Are you using Git inside _this_ SSH session? Or is Git running _unrelated_ to this SSH session?

Comment: git is running inside the SSH session
1. I connect to my laptop via SSH
2. Inside the SSH terminal I issue `git fetch` and get an access error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this answer had it backwards. You can find the original text [in its history](https://superuser.com/posts/1709195/revisions)!

---

You indicate that the host you SSH to somehow uses the SSH keys present on your local host. There's basically only one way this could happens: SSH Agent Forwarding is enabled somewhere. Check `~/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

You can find proof by using `ssh -v`. Just before the remote shell starts, it will print this line when agent forwarding is enabled:

> debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.

Comment: I edited my post. I'm using github inside the same terminal I'm doing SSH

Comment: Then you most likely have agent forwarding enabled. Check your SSH client config and/or use `ssh -v` to find out.

Comment: You are right. Turns out `ForwardAgent` was enabled for that host in my `desktop` `.ssh/config`